# Create tag also on origin in Gitahead

Tags: git, tags, gitahead

When I create a tag on my local repository

[image: Create tag]

it is created on my local repository.

[image: Select tag]

I do not know how to push this the origin located on GitHub.

[image: Context menu of tag]

I could push this to the remote repository on the command line by

```
git push origin v0.3.0
```

but I wonder if there is way to do this through the GUI of Gitahead.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution: From the menu "Remote" select "Push to" and then select v0.3.0 from the "Tags" tab of the displayed dialog.

[image]

Comment: thank you, I had the same issue. I hope they simplify the process