# Push tag after tag creation

Tags: git, gitahead

I have created a tag in GitAhead but forgot to check **Push to origin**. Is there a way to push that already locally created tag to origin?

[Answer]
[Create tag also on origin in Gitahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247117/create-tag-also-on-origin-in-gitahead)

Comment: I haven't use GitAhead before, but I imagine if you can view a list of tags you can right-click on a tag name and the context menu might have an option to push it.

Comment: Don't know what "GitAhead" is, but you can push local tags to your remote like this: `git push --follow-tags` (see [git push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---follow-tags) documentation.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew the git commands but I want to solve it the GitAhead way. I have also tried right clicking the tagged commit to see if there’s a push option but it doesn’t .

Comment: Yep, the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247117/create-tag-also-on-origin-in-gitahead Thanks!